# Display records/table from mysql. Issue

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want display data from mysql on my php page . Everything works well but...

I have two tables . Players and Combat .

On players I gave username,unique_id

On combat I have unique_id , kills , deaths .

I want split connect these two tables and display them using this code/table

[image]

My code

```
 <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbname");  
 $query ="SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY unique_id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Player Data</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3 align="center"> Player Data</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                          <thead>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td>username</td>  
                                    <td>unique_id</td>  

                               </tr>  
                          </thead>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo '  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["unique_id"].'</td>
                               </tr>  
                               ';  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#employee_data').DataTable();  
 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code rather than linking to it on an external site.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the current output and the expected output (together with some example data for your two tables). Currently, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish and where you're stuck.

Comment: @vascowhite Done

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Done .  I want add "kills" to my table on my page but data is on another "table" on mysql.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you make it for me? Idk how/where add this .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INNER JOIN` in SQL to connect two tables on a shared value.

I'm assuming that the value in `unique_id` is the column both tables have in common.

If you change your database query to:

```
SELECT 
    player.unique_id,  
    player.username,
    combat.kills,
    combat.deaths
FROM 
    player
INNER JOIN 
    combat ON player.unique_id = combat.unique_id
ORDER BY 
    player.unique_id DESC
```

This query will join both tables where the columns `unique_id` has the same value.

Now you can echo the content just like before:

```
<td>'.$row["username"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["unique_id"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["kills"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["deaths"].'</td>
```

You can read more about `INNER JOIN` here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx